# Node.js exits clean express starter app.js

Tags: node.js, macos, express, nvm

I have installed Express using:

 `nvm install -g express && nvm install -g express-generator`

Then I ran:

`express -c stylus my_app`

to create new blank app, and install dependencies:

`nvm install`

But, when I `node app.js` my output is blank/clean and node exits

```
$ node app.js
$
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Look at the generated code in app.js (and whatever other files are generated). Make sure that you don't have anything else running on the port used. We don't really have anything else to go on here.

Comment: I realized i was supposed to use "node bin/www" and now the server works, i don't get the "debug('Express server list..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new folder, place new app.js in folder. And put the following code in app.js:

```
var app = require('express')();
app.listen(8080, function (err) {
      if (err) { 
         console.log(err);
      } else {
         console.log("App started at port 8080");
      }    
});
```

This is blank express app. And then run in command line: `node app.js`

Comment: "try the following", next/next() is a special word

Answer (score 3):

For future people who encounter this question: make sure you call `app.listen([port number])`. If you don't call `.listen()`, your code will simply instantiate the app and then exit immediately.